# Have concurrent threads put items into a Hash Map

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to split up a loop requiring many iterations over a number of threads to increase speed performance. My program splits up the loop into n intervals where n is the number of threads and runs them concurrently. Whenever the loop reaches certain values it should store information into a ConcurrentHashMap in the outer class.

When using the debugger I get this notification:
`((Worker)this).md4 = Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'org.example.hashes.Engine' to 'org.example.hashes.Engine.Worker'`

```
public class Engine {
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> crackedPasswords = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final int NUM_THREADS;

    public Engine() {
        NUM_THREADS = numThreads;
    }

    public void runProcess() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);
        for(int i=1; i<=NUM_THREADS; i++) {
            long workload = numCombs/NUM_THREADS;
            Worker worker = new Worker(workload * (i-1), workload*i);
            executor.execute(worker);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
   }

   public ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> getCrackedPasswords() {
        return crackedPasswords;
    }

   class Worker implements Runnable {
        private final MD4 md4 = new MD4();
        private final long iterationStart;
        private final long iterationEnd;

        public Worker(long inStart, long inEnd) {
            this.iterationStart = inStart;
            this.iterationEnd = inEnd;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(long iteration=iterationStart; iteration<iterationEnd; iteration++) {
                checkHash(String.valueOf(currentPlain));
            }
        }

        private void checkHash(String plainText) {
            for(byte[] hashByte : hashBytes) {
                if (Arrays.equals(hashByte, md4.runDigest(plainText))){
                    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(hashByte.length*2);
                    for(byte b: hashByte)
                        hex.append(String.format("%02x", b));

                    crackedPasswords.putIfAbsent(hex.toString(), plainText);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The program ends up returning null. When instead of using an executor I create a thread and call run() it returns the proper value, but is obviously not concurrently running threads.

Comment: The existence of method `MD4Worker` is confusing here. Is that meant to be the constructor method name but misnamed?

Comment: You neglected to show your code containing `(Worker)this`.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I removed some code that was unrelated to the issue and forgot to rename it. (Worker)this is the instance of the worker class I believe

Comment: This code is weird. What is “`currentPlain`”? Shouldn’t the loop body depend on the iteration variable in some way? Why are you converting between values and strings back and forth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to wait for the parallel work to finish before exiting the application.

This could be done by calling
[`ExecutorService.awaitTermination(long, TimeUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) after `ExecutorService.shutdown()`

eg

```java
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);
for (int i=1; i<=NUM_THREADS; i++) { 
   ... 
}
executor.shutdown();
boolean terminated = executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);   
if (!terminated) {
   throw new RuntimeException("Work not finished after waiting 10 minutes");
}
```